# Using OAuth2.0 (Google API) on a kiosk

Tags: json, api, oauth, kiosk

I'm trying to set up a PC in kiosk mode that will display a list of events from a Google Calendar. I initially wanted to use the Google API for this (be it the JS client, Python client or other), but it seems that all of these require the user to consent via a page in the browser. This is not acceptable because it's a standalone system--there is no user to click on anything. The system will be on a daily power cycle so a 'consent once run forever' is also not possible.

Is there a way to use the authenticated (OAuth2.0) Google API to access calendar data without any user intervention whatsoever (except just a one-time initial setup)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what OAuth should be able to do. You should do a onetime setup (start he flow, authorize the request and get the tokens) and then store the tokens. Once the tokens are stored, you do NOT need any more user action as long as you have the tokens. The tokens would then be used to retrieve the data from the Google Calendar.